# Angular with Rails API: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, api

So I am deploying an Angular 5 app with a Rails 5 back-end. I can get the data to flow properly between the two locally, but trying to connect to the deployed version of the API (which is on Heroku) I run into some authorization issue. The error is:

```
Failed to load https://my_api.herokuapp.com/data.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
The response had HTTP status code 404.

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <URL> with MIME type application/json. 
See <URL> for more details.
```

Is this something I need to change within the Rails API or in Angular? The deployed Rails API is essentially the same as the local version so I'm not sure where the disconnect is coming from.

There are only two refrences to the API in Angular. I connect to it the same way that I do to the local server:

Angular, app-module.ts

```
  providers: [Angular2TokenService, AuthService, AuthGuard,
    // {provide: 'api', useValue: 'http://localhost:3000/'}
    {provide: 'api', useValue: 'https://my_ api.herokuapp.com/data.json'}
  ]
```

Perhaps it's my use of Angular2TokenService?

Angular, environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  token_auth_config: {
  // apiBase: 'http://localhost:3000'
  apiBase: 'https://my_api.herokuapp.com/data.json'
}};
```

Thanks! Let me know of any suggestions you might have or if you need clarification.

Comment: It's issue with CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) you have to handle with rails API by allowing cross-origin-headers in before_action of accessing you're API

Comment: You should be using [this](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to configure on Rails

Answer (score 0):

It's issue with CORS(cross-origin-resource-sharing). You can handle it by adding callback in your API like below:

```
def cors_set_access_control_headers
 headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = ENV['SERVER_URL'] || '*'
end
```

where SERVER_URL is your front-end server URL

Else you can use `gem 'rack-cors'` as suggested in comments by @Kedarnag Mukanahallipatna